# Generating sawtooth signal out of square/triangular signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I want to create a sawtooth signal generator. I know, how to build op-amp comparator to create a square wave. I also know, how i can get triangular signal by integrating comparator output with op-amp integrator.

What i don't know nor find is how do i get sawtooth signal out of square/triangular wave. Could someone explain this a bit and es

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A saw tooth generator circuit can be built using a constant current source to charge a capacitor in a linear ramp. A comparator is then set to monitor the ramp for its upper threshold. At the upper level the comparator then flips state and is used to discharge the capacitor quickly. If the comparator is setup with positive feedback so that it has both an upper and lower threshold then the comparator will flip back when the capacitor has discharged to the lower level. This would allow the cycle to repeat again. This would be a simple way to get a repeating sawtooth ramp. You may want to buffer the ramp with an opamp voltage follower depending on the type of load you want to use.

Note that it is not directly feasible to get a sawtooth waveform at the same frequency from a square wave or triangle wave. At least not without a lot of extra circuitry so it is generally best to generate your saw tooth separate from the square or triangle and then switch to the sawtooth when needed. Now that said it is entirely possible to setup a circuit that can be used to generate the square wave and triangle wave using the same set of comparators if you choose one function at a time.

Edit:
Here is a simulation circuit showing how a sawtooth generator circuit could be built. This example with nominal values runs at about 1kHz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your post by adding a schematics. TY

Comment: Sure. I'll add a typical saw tooth generator circuit.

Comment: One could design a circuit which, given a triangle wave of arbitrary frequency and DC offset, would--assuming "ideal" components, produce a sawtooth wave of the same frequency and DC offset.  Use sample/hold circuits to measure the upper and lower bounds of the triangle wave, and then during the rising portion compute "output = (input+min)/2", and during the falling portion "output = (3*max-input)/2".

Comment: I have tried this with R1=R6=R7=1.33K, R2=2.2K, R3=22K, C1=0.1uF, R3=R4=R9=10K and it didn't work.

Comment: You should put your circuit into LT-Spice (free at www.linear.com) and check out how the circuit works with those values. Then using an oscilloscope compare what you see in the simulation against the circuit that you built. This can lead to a better understanding of what you built, help get it debugged and give satisfaction that you learned something. BTW you didn't say what you did with R5. Note that R3, R4 and R5 are setting the threshold values for the comparator - changing them too much may render a non-functional circuit. (Cont next comment).

Comment: (Cont from previous comment). Your comparator choice may be important here too - speed, output type and input common mode range all play a role in this circuit.

Comment: There is also a common sawtooth generator circuit that you may want to look into that uses a 555 chip. In that circuit a constant current source similar to what I showed is used as the charge source of the capacitor so that the linear ramp is produced.

Comment: I would like to avoid 555 chip. For a comparator i used LM358N.

Comment: @71GA - Just so you know the LM358N is a dial op-amp. It should be able to function in this circuit topology.

Comment: Could you tell me what role do R6 and R5 have? Why are they even needed?

Comment: @71GA - R5 provides feedback from the output of the comparator back to the input to shift the threshold. Sets threshold on the (+) input higher when the output has gone high and lower when the output has gone low. This provides what is called hystersis and makes the comparator work similar to a Schmidt trigger logic gate. R6 was placed in the circuit to provide the pullup high level for when comparators of the open drain type are utilized. R6 would not be needed if the comparator had a push-pull output that swings both high and low.

Comment: In my previous comment regarding the chip type of the LM358N. I meant to say that it is a "dual op-amp".

Comment: This circuit hasnt worked for me. Is it possible that the reason is i used transistors: PNP c556b http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/motorola/BC557A.pdf and NPN c546b http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet2/d/0kq9ua20u27ka13c66efh960khpy.pdf