# Capacitor bank as a constant current source?

Tags: capacitor, constant-current, supercapacitor

Can a capacitor bank of high power density, be integrated to a circuit such that it acts as a constant current source to a load?

Even for a short duration of time.

Comment: What kind of load do you need to drive?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Simply treat the capacitor bank as if it were a battery.  That means that you need to add a constant-current circuit to the power source (capacitor bank) in order to get a constant current output.

Do note that the actual capacity of the cap bank is much, much less than either a primary or secondary battery of similar physical size.

Comment: Completely wrong. A capacitor is essentially a voltage source with variable current depending on load.

Comment: @Jack Creasey: Oh, Kay.  How would you describe a battery using your terms?

Comment: @DwayneRied. A battery is a constant voltage source (over a short period of time) and will supply as much current as it can limited only by the chemistry and architecture. If you remove the 'Yes' from your answer it actually reads almost correct …..but a capacitor or battery are NOT Constant current devices.

Comment: @Jack Creasey: Exactly the same as a capacitor bank.

Comment: @Jack Creasey: I think that we are getting tripped up by semantics.  But for large values of "C", you can treat a capacitor bank as if it were a battery.

Comment: @DwaneReid. I don't disagree, but the question was "Capacitor bank as a constant current source?" …..to which you answered 'Yes" …...care to modify that?

Comment: Last comment from me on this answer: please re-read my answer and note the 3rd paragraph where I state "Obviously, you need to add a constant current circuit . . .".  At no time did I suggest that a capacitor would act like a constant-current source.  I simply answered the initial question: "Can a capacitor bank . . .".

Comment: @JackCreasey I agree with DwayneReid, the question was not whether a capacitor could act as a constant current source but whether a capacitor could be "integrated to a circuit such that..." I interpret this (poorly worded) question to mean that some kind of circuitry is used with a capacitor to make a constant current source. I can see that other interpretations might occur, though.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Oxymoron - the last sentence contradicts the first!

Comment: @Chu No argument there...and only two sentences in the question! It is a very poor question, but EESE incentivizes quick responses and so the answers sometimes try to read the OP's mind. Hate the game, not the players.

Comment: @JackCreasey: I see what you are getting at.  I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A constant current source, as its name says, delivers the same current over a (wide) range of loads.

The opposite is a constant voltage source, which delivers the same voltage over a (wide) range of loads.

Over a short period a loaded capacitor behaves as a constant *voltage* source.

So **No**, a loaded capacitor can't be used as a constant current source. Unless you add a constant current circuit, but then every voltage source can be used.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor will not be the greatest choice for that particular usage, i recommand a battery instead.
But you can use a capacitor in this case with a correct circuit.

Some IC convert the output of capacitor to constant voltage, you just have to change it to constant current. Look at TI they have some ic that can suit your need.

Also if you say by high power density, super-capacitor. You have some application online that already use super-capacitor for long time usage (exemple: a tramway in Germany that only use super-capacitor between station). So yes your idea is ok.

A capacitor will have a "Punch" current but not for a long time (low energy density):
[image]
(From https://www.global.tdk.com/techmag/electronics_primer/vol1.htm)

You can make a circuit like that for your usage but we need more information about the duration and power.

Here the diagram of power stored by technologies:
[image]

[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312164269_Large-Scale_Nanographite_Exfoliation_for_Low-Cost_Metal-Free_Supercapacitors] ("Figure 1.1: Ragone plot showing the energy density versus power density of fuel cells, capacitors and batteries")

And this is a duplicate of other question on the site:
[Constant current source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53615/constant-current-source)
[Capacitor Discharge through Constant Current Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23020/capacitor-discharge-through-constant-current-source?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

A switched load of value R from a charged C bank of voltage Vc can deliver a constant current only for the duration of the tolerance of what is considered "constant"

Since I is hoped to be constant and **C** and **Vi** or initial voltage are constant, the result is ;

V(t) = Vi-dV/dt  where **\$Ic(t)=\dfrac{C~dV(t)}{dt}\$** and \$Ic(t)=\dfrac{Vc(t)}{R }\$ thus \$\dfrac{C ~dV_C(t)}{dt}=\dfrac{V_C(t)}{R} \$ or \$\dfrac{dV_C(t)}{V_C(t)}=RC\$

So if the tolerance for CC was 10% current droop = voltage droop then 
\$dt~ = 0.1 RC ~\$max

This assumes R is much greater than the ESR of the C bank to be able to neglect the additional $$ΔV = I*ESR$$ drop.