# Sawtooth generator adjustable from 100MHz-500MHz

Tags: oscillator, 555, waveform

I need an easy circuit that will generate sawtooth waves at adjustable 100MHz-500MHz (preferably set by a resistor) from 0V going up to 5V. The waves themselves does not have to be perfectly linear, it can be an upside-down exponential wave (as with charging a capacitor).

There's no x55-type that go on this frequency, but I've read this can also be done with other oscillators or counters. Problem is I don't know which one to pick.

This is not for RF.

EDIT:

This is not for radio propagation.

Comment: How is 100MHz to 500 MHz not RF?

Comment: What is the sawtooth signal for? Why a sawtooth and not a sine wave? What are you contacting it to?

Comment: This is not for radio propagation and is separate from my other projects.

Answer (score 3):

What do you need this for?

Sawtooth waves contain both even and odd harmonics and fairly large amplitude: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Synthesis_sawtooth.gif.

Going out to, say, the tenth harmonic for a fundamental of 100-500 Mhz is a big headache. You'll need to design a circuit that operates between 100 MHz and 5.5 GHz, and has linear phase response across the whole band. That's not a trivial task.

The most straightforward (although there's nothing straightforward about this) way I can think of doing it is feeding a clock generator IC into a high speed op amp and doing something like what's suggested in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53497/generating-sawtooth-signal-out-of-square-triangular-signal). You need to do a lot of modeling to get it to work right. Some problems I can forsee:

1. The opamp must be spec'd so that you have constant gain at the highest harmonic you plan to keep. This implies a gain-bandwidth product somewhere in the low GHz range.
2. You'll likely need some kind of output buffer amp, probably a MMIC, and you'll need to wideband match it. Depending how many harmonics you want to keep this becomes a pain as at the lower end you're dealing with lumped element devices and at the upper end microstrip construction.
3. Passives aren't ideal at these frequencies, not by a long shot. Take into account real-world Q and parasitics.
4. Microstrip is only quasi-TEM, and will suffer from significant dispersion in this application. This is bad, as the harmonics will arrive at the load at different times. You probably will have to use stripline instead as it's non-dispersive.

Basically, model the hell out of this thing in ADS/AWR/your microwave design package of choice.

Why do you feel you need to do this?

Comment: There are no harmonics as this is not for radio propagation -- as I added above through edit (when I said this is not for RF, it really isn't). So need to do it in terms of AC or any signal interpolation. This is a separate project other than 3 other I usually post questions for.

Comment: IMO sawtooth generation is very straight forward. Just google "555" and "sawtooth" and you get tons of result. I suppose this is because you're assuming I'll be synthesizing this from sine waves.

Comment: Although, to synthesize sawtooth that is inherently sinusoidal, maybe one can take a very high frequency AC at a very low voltage (1-3V). Then offset that with a sawtooth that a much, much lower frequency at a much higher voltage (90V ??). This is of course a chicken-and-egg problem, but at least you get something somewhat similar, but not identical signal. From what I gather, when dealing with harmonics the function gets a little funky at places the signal being reproduced (sawtooth) "pinches".

Comment: Of course when I said "when I said this is not for RF, it really isn't" 3 comments above, I meant: "when I said this is not for RF, it's really not radio propagation"

Comment: Of course there are still harmonics. Do you understand how the Fourier transform works?

Comment: And just because you're not feeding this into an antenna doesn't mean it's not RF. You're generating a signal which when bandlimited out to some high harmonic goes into the microwave range. No matter what you have to deal with that. The signal chain needs wideband linear phase matching, you need to compensate for frequency-dependent variation in your components, you need to use stripline on a PCB for it, and you need to ferry it to the load via good coax.

Comment: Again - what's this for?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not reproducing this from sinusoidal waves, simply linear sawtooth is all I need.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're synthesizing it, the signal still has harmonic content. Whether it comes from fourier synthesis or a ramp generator is irrelevant.

Comment: @Badadeeboop A sawtooth with no harmonics is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

You need an arbitrary waveform generator, with a sample rate high enough to make your sawtooth as sharp as you want it.

For a 500 MHz sawtooth, you will probably need 5 or 10 GSa/s.

These are certainly available, Keysight, Tektronix make them, but they're not very cheap.

You can look into making one, but to develop and tune such a circuit you'll need at least twice as much test equipment as that - signal generators and oscilloscopes capable of these sample rates themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to speculate without a clear description of the required waveshape and the associated source/load impedances, but in principle various non-sinusoidal waveforms can be generated without using active devices from the GHz part of the spectrum. For example, given a 10 V p-p sinewave at 500 MHz, a good approximation to a square wave rich in harmomics can be produced by clippimg the initially sinusoidal waveform using a pair of fast Schottky diodes. And from there to tilting waveforms.

George Berzins